# error calling a function in javascript for sharepoijnt

Tags: javascript, forms, sharepoint, relationship

I am trying to use the following code to open a child list new item on the edit item tab for the parent list.

It is not executing the function, could someone please help me. I am a novice at best.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ProductItem(newFormPath)
 {
 // Get the Query String values and split them out into the vals array
 var vals = new Object();
 var qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
 var args = qs.split("&");
for (var i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
 var nameVal = args[i].split("=");
var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+');
nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ');
vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
 }
 var IDColumn = vals["ID"];
window.location = newFormPath + “?ParentID=” + IDColumn;
 }
</script>
<a href=”javascript:ProductItem(‘[YOUR-SITE-PATH]/Lists/ChildTasks/NewForm.aspx’);”>Click here to add a new Task to this Contact</a>
```

i took out the actual website name. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What editor are you using to write your code? The quotes here: `“?ParentID=”` are invalid characters. Use double (`"`) or single (`'`) quotes. Like: `"?ParentID="`. Your last line as well, it also has invalid characters.

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin.

Comment: I'm writing directly in a Content Editor - I tried to revise the quotations but it still won't call to the function

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the quotes the function looks like it is being called. I added a `console.log` inside the function and commented out everything else to test.

I am not familiar with `location` but I don't think I can reproduce your expected output locally. So this is about as far as I can help.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ProductItem(newFormPath) {
    console.log('Inside function ProductItem', newFormPath)

    // Get the Query String values and split them out into the vals array
    // var vals = new Object()
    // var qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length)
    // var args = qs.split('&')
    // for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    //   var nameVal = args[i].split('=')
    //   var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+')
    //   nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ')
    //   vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1]
    // }
    // var IDColumn = vals['ID']
    // window.location = newFormPath + '?ParentID =' + IDColumn
  }
</script>
<a
   href="javascript:ProductItem('[YOUR-SITE-PATH]/Lists/ChildTasks/NewForm.aspx');">Click
  here to add a new Task to this Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did test your script in my local environment, you could try it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ProductItem(newFormPath) {
            // Get the Query String values and split them out into the vals array
            var vals = new Object();
            var qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
            var args = qs.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                var nameVal = args[i].split("=");
                var temp = unescape(nameVal[1]).split('+');
                nameVal[1] = temp.join(' ');
                vals[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
            }
            var IDColumn = vals["ID"];
            window.location = newFormPath + "?ParentID =" + IDColumn;
        }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:ProductItem('http://sp/Lists/MyTasks/NewForm.aspx');">Click here to add a new Task to this Contact</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Lee - I'm still getting a blank page when i click on the output... is it working for you?

Comment: Hey Lee, it appears this isn't working on Sharepoint2013 specifically. Do you have any ideas?